# Interpolation in style attribute

Tags: angularjs, interpolation

This is regarding https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#known-issues

The documentation says that "Your changes are likely to be overwritten, when the original string gets evaluated."

With the example:

```
style="color: {{ 'orange' }}; font-weight: {{ 'bold' }};")
```

Can someone please explain what documents is trying to highlight?

Comment: You can change the same attributes with `ng-style`, it could be overwritten

Comment: Thanks @Mistalis for your reply. Do you mean using style = "...{{..}}..." and ng-style= "..." both together could cause the problem? If yes, then i was aware of that, but the sentence doesn't looks to be saying the same. What does "your change" and "original string" means?

Comment: "**You should avoid dynamically changing the content of an interpolated string"**. As I understand, `ng-style` is a pretty good example of a dynamic change of the content.

Comment: Still i am not clear :( .. The above line says what should be done, but i am looking for reason why it should be done, what could be the issue if use as

style="color: {{ 'orange' }}; font-weight: {{ 'bold' }};")

Comment: I think that this point from the documentation explains it in more details:  There is no guarantee that it works for every directive, because interpolation itself is a directive. If another directive accesses attribute data before interpolation has run, it will get the raw interpolation markup and not data.